# Why is a microwave oven equipped with a waveguide?

Tags: microwave, waveguide, magnetron

In a microwave oven, the magnetron connects to the waveguide.  Magnetrons produce microwaves, which are guided into the cooking chamber by waveguides.

Why don't we directly connect the magnetron to the cooking chamber?

Comment: The independent union of waveguides would set up a picket line otherwise.

Comment: :) :) :) :) :) :)

Comment: @Kartman I didn't understand your point. Can you elaborate it more?

Comment: @Prerna:  Kartman's comment was a joke.

Answer (score 0):

The stirrer cannot be (as far as I can tell) directly positioned close to the magnetron itself because it will burn. Given that microwave ovens (of every type that I know of) use a stirrer, it makes sense to connect the microwave to the stirrer via the only sensible means possible; a waveguide: -

[image]

Picture from [here](http://www2.ee.ic.ac.uk/ngai-han.liu08/yr2proj/magnetron.htm).

I would also add that anything rotating in the near-field of the magnetron is likely to be subject to very strong electric and magnetic fields that might even disrupt the operation of the magnetron (apart from being subject to higher stress).

Comment: @Andy aka As far as I know now a days, a microwave oven doesn't have stirrer.

Comment: @Prerna maybe you'd like to link to one that doesn't have a stirrer.

Comment: @Andyaka : Prerna is right. Basically every microwave oven one would buy today (for personal use) does not have a stirrer. It's just a short microwave launcher + a horn antenna.